# How to display a value of field in crosstab total row?

Tags: jasper-reports, crosstab

I have two problems with my Crosstab component.

1. In my Crosstab I have total row at the beginning of tab and I want to display value from my field in each column. So I created field and put it in total cell. While compiling I've got error "field not found" but when I put this field into details band it is displaying correctly.
2. Other case. Can I add several total row to my Cross tab and display there values from my Fields?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To display the value in cross tab you need to **create a measure**

**Example**

```xml
<measure name="myField" class="java.lang.String">
    <measureExpression><![CDATA[$F{myField}]]></measureExpression>
</measure>
```

**Note:** the measure can be a simple representation of a field (as in example), with `calculation="Nothing"` (default value if not indicated), remember to set correct class (same as field)

Now you can **add the measure `$V{myField}` to your crosstab cell**:

```xml
<textField>
   <reportElement style="Crosstab Data Text" x="0" y="12" width="50" height="12" uuid="2a004def-c91d-40be-ba2a-fac8763fca7b"/>
   <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
      <font size="8"/>
      <paragraph lineSpacing="Single"/>
   </textElement>
    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{myField}]]></textFieldExpression>
</textField>
```

As for you second question *"Can I add several total row to my Cross tab"?*, this is a bit unclear, you will get a total row as indicated by the `totalPosition` attribute on the `rowGroup`/`columnGroup` and you can add as many group's as you like.

> **"Start"** - totals are to be positioned before the other buckets.
>
> **"End"** - totals are to be positioned at the end of the other buckets.
>
> **"None"** - total are not required for this bucket.

Comment of OP:
*To solve second problem I just created general rows in Column Header band.* – Tomasz Iwaszko

Comment: Thanks. To solve second problem I just created general rows in Column Header band.